# OS X Delete all odd numbered files

Tags: bash, osx-mountain-lion

I am editing an app where they are halving the frame rate on 12,000 files of a 360 view because the file is too large.  I have tried things listed in other threads but get 
"bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"'
"bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('

e.g. for %F in (*1.jpg *3.jpg *5.jpg *7.jpg *9.jpg) do move "%%F" "temp\"

or

for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg^|findstr /irc:"[13579].jpg$"') do move "%F" "temp"

Anyone know the fix for that?  There are 25 subfolders, ideally I'd like to just move the files to another directory with the same directory structure so I can easily recombine them if they change their mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commands you are trying do not seem to be `bash` syntax - they look more like Windows command shell stuff.

Try this instead:

```
mv -i */*[13579].jpg temp/.
```

`mv -i` will ask you to confirm if you attempt to overwrite a file (if two of the subdirectories have files with the same name). `*/*[13579].jpg` means all files in any subdirectory that end with an odd digit followed by ".jpg", and `temp/.` is the destination directory.

Comment: That did it, thanks for the help.  I swear those said to use bash and not sh in the comments, but maybe they meant for windows?